# Acid catalysed mechanism of the addition of alcohols to alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, erratum

[image]

[image]

I believe that this mechanism is false. 
The protonated ether would in my opinion give a proton to methanol rather than $\ce{H2SO4}$ because the protonated $\ce{CH3OH}$ is more stable than $\ce{H2SO4}$.
Can someone confirm my thought?

Comment: pKa of H2SO4 is -9
pKa of CH3OH2+ is -2.5

Comment: Dissenter's analysis is pretty much on target. The one thing I'd add, you are correct that the proton is probably given to back to methanol rather than bisulfate because there is probably a drop of acid and a lot of methanol.  But thermodynamics will win out and eventually the proton will be transferred from protonated methanol to the bisulfate anion to regenerate the acid which, as Dissenter noted, is a catalyst - not to be consumed.

Comment: Protonating HSO4- in the presence of methanol is thermodynamically favorable?

Comment: Ron, which thermodynamic property are you stating? From my current perception of things, I think the protonated methanol would NOT transfer the proton to make H2SO4.

Comment: Isn't HSO4- a stronger base than neutral CH3OH?  How would you regenerate the catalyst H2SO4?

Comment: pKa of HOSO3- is ~1; pKa of CH3OH is ~16. This suggests to me that methanol is a better base.

Comment: I agree that HSO4- is a stronger acid, but is it also a stronger base than methanol? How do you regenerate the catalyst?

Comment: I don't know, could you please clarify? If HSO4- is a stronger acid than methanol that means HSO4- is a weaker base than methanol.

Comment: I just fall back to show me how you regenerate the catalyst?

Comment: What is the catalyst? I don't know if it's really sulfuric acid.

Comment: The figure says that the catalyst is H2SO4.  HSO4- has another ionizable proton so it is an acid, but what its pKb?

Comment: Why pKb if we're in methanol solvent? I was only using pKb as a rule of thumb; as a tool to rank the basicities on a relative basis. Also yes the figure says sulfuric acid is the catalyst but I don't necessarily agree.

Comment: HSO4- is an acid and a base

Comment: It is important to realize, that $\ce{H2SO4}$ is not the catalytically active species. It is also important to know that sulfuric acid always comes with water. The catalytic species is therefore either $\ce{H3+O}$ or $\ce{H2+OMe}$ as these are present in equilibrium. The scheme is only a sequence of reaction steps, it is no [reaction mechanism](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03804.html) as it completely lacks transition sates. (It is also omitted that the product has to be reprocessed in aqueous solution.)

Comment: What do you mean reprocessed in aqueous solution? And what if the problem meant liquid/pure sulfuric acid?

Comment: @Dissenter (If you are referring to a comment, then you should tag the person with `@` so that s/he gets the message.) A reaction never stops with what is proposed with by the 'reaction mechanism', the product has usually to be quenched or otherwise reprocessed and after that purified. Pure sulfuric acid is almost never used since it would decompose almost any organic compound straight away. The autoprotolysis is even stronger in $\ce{H2SO4}$: $$\ce{2H2SO4 <=> H3+O + [HS2O7]^{-}}$$ It always comes with water.

Comment: @Martin what is the auto ionization constant for sulfuric acid?

Comment: @Dissenter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid#Polarity_and_conductivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The protonated ether would in my opinion give a proton to methanol
>   rather than H2SO4

I don't think sulfuric acid is gaining any protons here. You mean hydrogen sulfate ion, correct?

> Can someone confirm my thought?

The mechanism is acid-*catalyzed* dehydration, so the acid must be regenerated. Catalysts are by definition not consumed over the course of a reaction. Now, whether the acid is *actually* sulfuric acid is debatable, and in my mind, unlikely, given the leveling effect and that the solvent is methanol.

The leveling effect states that the strongest acid that can exist in high concentration in a particular solvent is the conjugate acid of the solvent. The conjugate acid of methanol has a pKa of ~ -2.5, while the pKa of sulfuric acid is ~ -9. Thus, sulfuric acid can't exist in high concentration in methanol. Sulfuric acid would immediately protonate the strongest base in the system. Therefore, it appears to me that the *acting* acid is *not* sulfuric acid. Perhaps it is protonated methanol ion.

Or perhaps it is the case that sulfuric acid reacts directly with the alkene. Whether sulfuric acid would be regenerated in this particular solvent, however, is questionable at best, given sulfuric acid's extreme thermodynamic *instability* in methanol. If it were regenerated, then the sulfuric acid would again protonate the strongest base in the system.

**Of course, thermodynamic considerations are important, but so are kinetic considerations.** Do remember that there is likely *a lot* more solvent than there is sulfuric acid and substrate (the alkene). So it seems most likely that the *acting* acid is protonated methanol - it is a lot more likely for sulfuric acid to bump into a methanol molecule rather than an alkene molecule.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Yes, I meant HSO4-

Comment: Can you explain why the hydrogen sulfate ion would attack instead of methanol?

Comment: That's a good question. What's the solvent?

Comment: My textbook oversimplifies again :9

Comment: I think so; is this Wade? This mechanism doesn't seem to make too much sense. We know that protonated methanol is a weaker acid than sulfuric acid. And we know from the leveling effect that the strongest acid that can exist in high conc. in a solvent system is the conjugate acid of the solvent. This suggests that the actual acid isn't sulfuric acid but rather hydrogen sulfate ion. Or protonated methanol.

Comment: I'll upload the question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/fn2yxyU
Solomon's, not Wade's.

Comment: I think matters have been oversimplified.

Comment: Do you agree that in case where methanol is the solvent, it would be CH3OH that would attack? I could discuss it with my teacher and come back. But I think we make more sense than the book.

Comment: You mean would methanol do the deprotonation?

Comment: I read your edited answer. We seem to agree. :)

Comment: I mean it might be the case that the alkene gets the proton from sulfuric acid before sulfuric acid protonates the solvent. I don't know. I'm just speaking from a thermodynamic standpoint.

Comment: I believe the sulfuric acid actually attacks the alkene first. This would make more sense because H-OR are more acidic than alkenes. So, adding a proton would be easier on an alkene.

Comment: Hey looks like we agree again.

Comment: Great, I'll check your answer. I think we made our point ;)

Comment: Weird: look at the following problem from the same textbook.
http://imgur.com/dcqpZqR

Comment: Which problem? Can you show me?

Comment: They show the protonated methanol.

Comment: I don't quite agree with that either because it should be the alkene getting protonated, not the methanol. In any case at least the end product is the same regardless of which pathway taken!

Comment: Very confusing!

Comment: do you know that the triple equality sign showing the hydride shift means in the last uploaded picture?

Comment: It could be the fact that there is a whole lot more solvent than there is substrate (alkene) so the methanol could indeed be protonated to a significant degree.

Comment: The three lines just means "equivalent" in chemistry. The triple lines are not indicating a hydride shift; it is just indicating that the two pentagons are the same (one is just purposely distorted as to make clear the hydride shift; the other has been adjusted to look pretty when printed).

Comment: @yolo123 When it comes to reaction mechanisms you have to understand, that these are only the most likely steps that are going to happen. Also the depiction of most reaction mechanisms is only a reaction sequence. A mechanism has always to include the transition states. At the same time, there are many reactions happening simultaneously, and there are also quite many equilibria involved. A mechanism is never as simple as it is depicted in most organic chemistry textbooks. It is only a guideline to reactivity of certain species.

Answer (score 5):

The short version: You are correct, the schematic drawing is not the correct mechanism and it does also not provide the most likely path. For a training exercise it is close enough though. It shows the most important steps and it conserves stoichiometry.

---

The depicted scheme does not show a reaction mechanism in the sense of the definition given in the [goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03804.html). A reaction mechanism always also has to include transition states, that lead to the respective products. It is rather a reaction sequence, that shows the most important steps. In this sense, the stoichiometry has to be conserved and in this sense it is as correct as it could be.

Noteworthy is, that the catalytically active species is not [sulfuric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid), but instead a mixture of hydronium and protonated methanol, $\ce{H3+O/H2+OCH3}$. Sulfuric acid is such a strong acid, that it is capable of protonating any solvent that has a lone pair, even itself via autoprotolysis (in concentrated $98\%$ solution). $$\ce{2H2SO4 <=> [H3SO4]+ + [HSO4]- <=> H3+O + [HS2O7]- <=> H2O + H2S2O7}$$
The use of concentrated sulfuric in organic synthesis is usually not advisable, since its dehydration property can quickly decompose many organic compounds that contain hydroxyl groups. The use of diluted sulfuric acid (either in water or alcohols) is therefore much more common.

It is only logical, that sulfuric acid will protonate methanol, which can be considered a preceding equilibrium. $$\ce{H2SO4 + HOCH3 <=> H2+OCH3 + [HSO4]- }$$
Since methanol is also the solvent and the acid is only available in catalytic amounts, it is feasible to assume, that the equilibrium lies entirely on the right.

It is also important, that the last step must be also in equilibrium, since it is only the protonation/deprotonation of an ether. Here again we have much more methanol than product, so that the equilibrium will most likely be entirely on the product side.

A more descriptive mechanism would be the following:
[image: long mechanism]

For simplicity and sufficiently accurate bond formation and breaking is indicated by arrows, omitting the transition states. Resulting a slightly simplified picture. However, the preceding equilibrium - as you noted - should not be omitted. This formulation of the mechanism is particularly important for many simple organic reactions, as it focusses entirely on the reactants and products (and to a minor extent on the reactive intermediates).
[image: short mechanism]

When it comes to more complex reactions, e.g. with asymmetric catalysts it is often much better to include the transition states.

From this it can also be seen, that the choice of sulfuric acid is somewhat arbitrary, as most acids would do the same. However, sulfuric acid is often used, since bisulfate and sulfate are very weak nucleophiles.

---

*Additional note*
In all schemes only the most likely path is shown. Any possible side reactions, like concerted [2+2] cycloaddition, have been omitted.

Comment: Why hydronium ion? Where does that come from? I understand that we're not dealing with pure sulfuric acid but your equilibria do not show where the water can come from.

Comment: @Dissenter, even assuming the reagents were classified as anhydrous, the autoprotolysis and related self-ionization equilibria (which Martin described) of sulfuric acid would result in a hodgepodge of species. Greenwood & Earnshaw note the following species present in pure sulfuric acid (in order of decreasing abundance, with $\ce{H2SO4}$ itself being the solvent): $\ce{HSO4^{-}, H3SO4^{+}, H3O^{+}, HS2O7^{-}, H2S2O7, H2O}$. Of course, when added in catalytic quantities, they won't be the dominant species.